# Image halfway on top of DIV

Tags: html, css

In my application I have a centered main div. Now I would like to get my logo halfway on top of the DIV. As shown in the picture:

[image]

I got this working, however, when my screensize changes, the image is located on the wrong place.

```
<div class="is-vertical-center">
  <div class="box">
      <div class="text-center">
        <img class="img-on-top" src="assets/logo.png">
      </div>
      <div class="router-outlet">
        <div class="pure-g">
          <div class="pure-u-1-1">
              <h5>Start</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pure-g">
          <div class="pure-u-1-1">
              <p>
                 Welcome Lorem ipsum
              </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.is-vertical-center {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  background-color: $color-ts-main-flat;
  border: 1px solid $color-ts-main-border;
  border-radius: 4px;
  max-width: 30%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center !important;
}

.img-on-top {
  top:0;
  margin-top:5%;
  position:absolute;
  right: 50%;
}

.router-outlet {
  flex: 1 0 100px;
  background-color:blue;

  /* stretch element immediately following the router-outlet element within the same parent element.
   * This is the element injected by angular (Assumption)
   */
  router-outlet + * {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

I made a fiddle, can someone point me in the right direction?

https://jsfiddle.net/x78a3oyj/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi - @Matheno  any change advance thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add [transform3d](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate3d) the the child element

```
.img-on-top {
    top: 0;
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;/*change to left*/
    width: 60px; /*set a width*/
    background: hsl(106, 100%, 34%);
}
```

then on the parent element, set `position relative`

```
.box {
  background-color: $color-ts-main-flat;
  border: 1px solid $color-ts-main-border;
  border-radius: 4px;
  max-width: 30%;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;/*add this*/
  background: hsl(0, 100%, 50%);
  margin-top: 3rem;
}
```

you here is the final code:

```css
.is-vertical-center {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  background-color: $color-ts-main-flat;
  border: 1px solid $color-ts-main-border;
  border-radius: 4px;
  max-width: 30%;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  background: hsl(0, 100%, 50%);
  margin-top: 3rem;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center !important;
}

.img-on-top {
    top: 0;
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background: hsl(106, 100%, 34%);
}

.router-outlet {
  flex: 1 0 100px;
  background-color:blue;

  /* stretch element immediately following the router-outlet element within the same parent element.
   * This is the element injected by angular (Assumption)
   */
  router-outlet + * {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="is-vertical-center">
  <div class="box">
      <div class="text-center">
        <img class="img-on-top" src="assets/logo.png">
      </div>
      <div class="router-outlet">
        <div class="pure-g">
          <div class="pure-u-1-1">
              <h5>Start</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pure-g">
          <div class="pure-u-1-1">
              <p>
                 Welcome Lorem ipsum
              </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code - top image

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.is-vertical-center {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  background-color: $color-ts-main-flat;
  border: 1px solid $color-ts-main-border;
  border-radius: 4px;
  max-width: 30%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center !important;
}

.img-on-top {
  top: 10px;
  margin-top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
}

.router-outlet {
  flex: 1 0 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  /* stretch element immediately following the router-outlet element within the same parent element.
           * This is the element injected by angular (Assumption)
           */
}

.router-outlet+* {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="is-vertical-center">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="text-center">
      <img class="img-on-top" src="assets/logo.png">
    </div>
    <div class="router-outlet">
      <div class="pure-g">
        <div class="pure-u-1-1">
          <h5>Start</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="pure-g">
        <div class="pure-u-1-1">
          <p>
            Welcome Lorem ipsum
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```